# Using Newton's Law of Universal Gravitation to find distance (r), with the question not giving sufficient information to substitute into the equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, classical-mechanics

The problem is described as follows:

Newton's Law of Universal Gravitation: $F=G \frac{m_1 m_2}{r^2}$ for any point masses $m_1,m_2$ with the distance between them $r$.

The factor $G≈6.67∙10^{-11}  N(m/kg)^2$ is a universal constant.

Denote the mass of Earth as $m_E≈5.972∙10^{24}  kg$, 
the mass of the Moon as $m_M≈7.348∙10^{22}  kg$.

The unknown mass of the object will be $m$ and the distance in question will be $R$.

Then the distance between the object and Earth is  $\frac{1}{10} R$
and the distance between the object and the Moon is $\frac{9}{10} R$.
The force from the Moon and Earth acting on the object is equal.

Now, I worked on the problem and found that from the law we obtain: 
$$G \frac{mm_E}{\left(\frac{9}{10} R\right)^2} =G \frac{mm_M}{\left(\frac{1}{10} R\right)^2}$$

It seems like there is no solution to the question as not enough information is given. However, I was given this question as an assignment in math class and believe that steps should be shown towards a solution whether it exists or not. I fail to see how to solve this problem, at least to an approximate value, which is what is needed. If anybody knows, help will be immensely appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The question is contradictory.  As the earth's mass is higher than the moon's mass and the object is $9$ times closer to the earth, the earth's attraction will be $9^2\frac {m_E}{m_M}\approx 81 \cdot 81.3$  It appears the object should be about $9$ times closer to the moon than to the earth to make the gravitational forces (almost) equal.  You don't say what the "distance in question $R$" is.  I suspect it is the distance from the earth to the moon and you are to find the location where the gravitational forces are equal.  It will be about $1/10$ of the way from the moon to the earth, but maybe you are expected to get a more precise answer.  You don't have anything to set $R$ in the data you have presented.  You also don't say what you are asked to solve for.  What is the question?

Comment: The object isn't 9 times closer to the Earth. It is 9/10 of the distance from Earth to Moon, or 1/10 of the distance away from the Moon. And the R is the variable to be solved for (about 384,400 km distance from moon to Earth). Thanks a lot if you decide to help!

Comment: As you posted, "the distance between the object and Earth is \frac 1{10}R$".  That appears to be a typo, as it is correct later.  The $9:1$ ratio in distances is determinable by the ratio of the masses, but you have no information to determine the earth-moon distance in the problem.  They could be 100 m apart with the object 10 m from the moon and the forces would balance.

Comment: Oh okay I see. Well, I'll here is the original phrasing of the problem:

Comment: Newton's Law of Universal Gravitation: F=(Gm1m2) / r^2

Earth mass = 5.972 X 10^24 kg

Moon mass = 7.348 X 10^22 kg

G = 6.67 X 10^-11

Comment: An object of unknown mass is placed directly between the Earth and the Moon such that the forces of gravity acting on the object are equal from both the Earth and the Moon. The distance from the Moon to the object is exactly one tenth of the distance from the Moon to Earth. Using the above formula, determine the distance from the Moon to the Earth.

Comment: If this is insufficient to solve the problem, at least an approximate answer is needed, with steps, by the question on the assignment. Thanks!

Comment: As I said last time, there is nothing to set the scale.  $R$ could be any number.  The mass ratio is sufficient to get the distance ratio, but that is all.

Comment: So my teacher is crazy...

Comment: I wouldn't say crazy just for one homework problem that is missing information.

Comment: bad joke, agree. Thank you very much for your time. sorry the question was useless.